# why I can't append directly after a split in python

Tags: python

```
test = "123213 32543543 52354 234 34"
a = test.split().append("sd")
print (a)
```

The above code will give me a None in output, while the following code will output a list:

```
test = "123213 32543543 52354 234 34"
a = test.split()
a.append("sd")
print (a)
```

Can anyone explain it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is because [`.append()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) list operation returns `None`.**

```
In [1]: list1 = [1,2,3,4] # some list

In [2]: a = list1.append(5) # append '5' to the list and assign return value to 'a'

In [3]: print a
None # means '.append()' operation returned None

In [4]: list1 
Out[4]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [5]: list1.append(6) 

In [6]: list1
Out[6]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

`some_list.append()` doesn't return the list `some_list`, it returns `None`, that's why